# Регистрация с помощью библеотеки vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Нужно сделать регистрацию на сайте. Чтобы с разных страниц данные собирались в один файл json. И этот файл отправлялся на сервер. И была кнопка отменить, с помощью которой файл очищался. Все это при помощи библеотеки vue.js. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.